# mysql split one column to multiple column

Tags: mysql, database

I wanted to split my data of a column, which is coming as text format and delimited by '| '

```
0190000000001000000000| 0150000000002500000000| 0190000000003500000000|
```

Like in the above column data there are three parts. These parts of data can be increased or decreased as per data logged by the system.

Could any one please help me to spilt the above text type .

Comment: You'll have to use a programming language for that not just mysql. As you can create a function that splits in SQL but it would never return an array, so doing what you want only with mysql is close to impossible.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online explaining how to do this, or at least acces an element of that list. ([example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)) But that kind of thing reveals a very poor data structure if you ask me. If you have multiple data, you should have multiple fields and/or multiple records somehow...

Comment: @Bartdude, I think that's what he's trying to do, from what I understand he's trying to fix his table structure

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `substring_index()`, but to get the individual values, you need to use the function twice:

```
select substring_index(col, '|', 1) as element_1,
       substring_index(substring_index(col, '|', 2), '|', -1) as element_2,
       substring_index(substring_index(col, '|', 3), '|', -1) as element_3
```

You can extend this indefinitely to the nth element.  But there is a catch.  If a column only has two values, then you will get repeated values.  Fixing this requires a bit more work.  Here is one method:

```
select substring_index(col, '|', 1) as element_1,
       (case when substring_index(col, '|', 2) = substring_index(col, '|', 1) then NULL
             else substring_index(substring_index(col, '|', 2), '|', -1)
        end) as element_2,
       (case when substring_index(col, '|', 3) = substring_index(col, '|', 2) then NULL
             else substring_index(substring_index(col, '|', 3), '|', -1)
        end) as element_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUBSTRING_INDEX() function to achieve this. also you need to use loops to get all the 3 splitted data.

For Substring_index reference,
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff and Harish Chinju

Comment: Please change your question as resolved. So others can get help from this. :)